# Failed to deploy Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment

I cannot deploy my app on Heroku as this is the error that I am getting;

I used this website to deploy my app to Heroku => https://betterprogramming.pub/deploy-your-app-for-free-in-7-easy-steps-thanks-to-heroku-dfd0f387edd0
Got this message;

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz     
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
remote:  !
remote:  !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
remote:  !
remote:  !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure.
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
remote:  !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
remote:  !     following files:
remote:  !
remote:  !     client/
remote:  !     Procfile
remote:  !     README.md
remote:  !     smart_contract/
remote:  !
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation
remote:
remote:
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to arcane-springs-89425.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-springs-89425.git
```

The code “git push heroku master” fails for the push-and-deploy process. I haven’t been given an URL where I could see my app.

Steps I took ;

- change the buildpack to node.js (I'm using blockchain, stability, metamask)
  git add Procfile
  git commit -a -m "Configuration to deploy to heroku"
  git push heroku master

The website https://git.heroku.com/arcane-springs-89425.git says "Method Not Allowed" in on a blank page.

Comment: That is the _least_ helpful part of the output. Please [edit] your question and show us all the errors that precede it.

Comment: Thanks! Just added more information. I tried deploying without adding a build pack and with adding node.js ( my front end contains package.json/package-lock.json)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking for help on how to push my code into heroku master/main. Doesn't recognise my code language.,

Comment: This error means you don't have a `package.json` in the root (top) folder of your project. Do you have a `package.json` anywhere in your codebase? Do you have any Node.js dependencies?

Comment: I have it inside the client folder and I don't have Node.js file. Only package.json